# Запрос из PMA. Подскажите чего не хватает, может способ реализации устарел и можно более качественно прописать.

Tags: php, база-данных, phpmyadmin

[image: таблица из PMA]

```
$link = mysqli_connect('host','name','password ','database');
    if (!$link) {
                die('---Ошибка соединения---: ' . mysql_error());
    }
                echo '---Успешно соединились---';

$query = sprintf("SELECT * FROM infoboard WHERE name, subject, start_datetime, end_datetime, message");

$result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
    if (!$result) {                                             
        $message  = 'Неверный запрос: ' . mysql_error() . "\n"; 
        $message .= 'Запрос: '."<br>" . $query;                 
        die($message);                                          
    }                                                           
$data = mysqli_fetch_all($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);

    foreach ($data as $item) {

        echo "Тип:  ".$item['Name']."<br>";
        echo "Категория:  ".$item['subject']."<br>";
        echo "Дата начала: ".$item['start_datetime']."<br>";
        echo "Дата завершения: ".$item['end_datetime']."<br>";
        echo "Сообщение: ".$item['message']."<br>";
    }

    mysql_free_result($result);

   ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Если вы не хотите грузить запрос всеми столбцами, то стоит запрос выполнить именно так:

```
SELECT name, subject, start_datetime, end_datetime, message FROM infoboard
```

Ваш запрос

```
SELECT * FROM infoboard WHERE name, subject, start_datetime, end_datetime, message
```

Категорически неверен. Прочитайте как правильно составлять запросы, в особенности оператор WHERE